# What are the precise rules for inventory sorting feature in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

With the new update a new button has appeared. It says "Sort inventory":

[image: image description]

When you click it, items in your items will be reordered and colored, presumably based on what type are they according to the algorithm:

[image: image description]

Items marked as favourite will be unaffected. However it's entirely unclear what order applies to items of the same type. I was hoping to sort all my potions by name. That's not what is applied, as you can see here:

[image: image description]

So what are the **precise** rules for sorting items, their colors and order of the items of the same type? This is a new feature, I'm sure other people are also curious how does it work...

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer That seems like a reasonable guess. It is supported by the experiment with potions, I'm quite sure builder potion is recent addition.

Comment: You could use ILSpy to decompile the program and find out.

Comment: I think it sorts by color rarity, if it doesn't, it probably does what @DanmakuGrazer  said.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is false. The items are sorted by type (i.e. melee weapon, ranged weapon, block etc.), and the colours do not correlate with the rarity. This can be seen in that the copper shortsword, with a white rarity, is light pink when sorted.

Answer (score -2):

Items sort by rarity (color) from most valuable to least valuable (according to rarity, not actual price), grey colored items being the least valuable and either rainbow or amber being the most valuable.

For more about rarity, please visit [this page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Rarity).

Answer (score -3):

After some testing I have think it is based on what type of item it is because accesories are the same color pickaxes are the same axes are the same summoning weapons are the same etc. It is very specific and it would take a lot if test ing to see what all possible groups are